# New router messed up server 2003 setup

Tags: firewall, routing, internet, dmz

We were sent a new 2wire router today configured it as best we can to match the old bt voyager.

We've also got X static IP's. We've manage to get our webserver on one of the new IP's public facing.

then we use a hardware firewall which is in a DMZ again with a different static IP.
This firewall then is our gateway for our internal LAN. with a few servers  etc. 
The problem we're having is only our PDC (primary Domain controller which has exchange 2003 on) can't ping externally even an external IP.

We've connected laptops to the 2wire router and obtain a private ip 192.168.1.X and it works fine can ping etc.

our other servers with an internal ip behind the firewall can ping out fine.

We've connected to the firewalls logging console and the pings from the server are allowed through so its fine there.

The server in question is a Windows server 2003 R2 Enterprise SP2 + Exchange 2003

Server doesn't have firewall turned on. it has static private IP .. gateway is pointing to the right one

External Static IP is routing fine inwards

We've ran out of ideas .. help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We sorted the problem... in the end we didnt have time to trouble shoot and find the cause after an entire afternoons work,

therefore we changed the servers internal IP address tried ping'ing out and it worked so we changed the DNS servers match the new setup and changed the NAT rules and everything seems to be tickadeebooo :D